# How to get the text typed in an EditText for android using Python?

Tags: android, python, xml, android-edittext

I used the xml below to design the layout of my android app. I used the EditText field to get an input from the user.

```
<EditText android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/editText1"
    android:tag="Tag Me"
    android:inputType="text">
            <requestFocus></requestFocus>
</EditText>
```

How do I get the text typed in that `EditText` and print it using Python?

Answer (score 0):

You can't use Python, Android programming is done in Java.  You can get the text from the `EditText` as follows (in Java):

```
EditText et = (EditText)findViewById( R.id.editText1 );
String s = et.getText().toString();
```

If you're asking how to send that text to a webserver that uses Python, that's quite a bit more complicated.

Comment: I have actually used python in developing the android app. Here's the link of my guide in programming it: https://code.google.com/p/android-scripting/wiki/FullScreenUI